# What will be the fastest way to access an element from a collection?

Tags: c#

What will be the fastest way to access an element from a collection?

I am thinking should be in the order (low to high):

Indexing an Array <= indexing a collection/list <= use key on Dictionary

But I am not sure...

1) Is indexing an array has same speed as indexing a list?

2) And will the indexing speed will grows as the size of the array/list grows?

From my understanding... indexing array should kind of using a pointer to point to the index of the element, which is caculated by the element size. So it should has same speed as indexing collection/list?

From what I know if we use Dictionary to look for a value, the speed of getting a value will grows as the size of Dictionary grows.

3) I just wonder what will be the fastest way to access an element from a collection?

Have been wondering for long time is my assumption is correct :)

Thanks

Comment: "Have been wondering for long time" Now there's a problem.

Comment: :p that's why I want to clean it up now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# a List is backed by an array, so both an array and a list/collection can access elements by indexing in O(1) time.  Performance for a Dictionary is similar because it is backed by a hash table.  However, it should be noted that the performance of access on a hash table is relative to the quality of the hash function and the number of collisions which occur in a particular data set.  In C#, each type may override `GetHashCode()`, which will determine the hash function and thus the performance of accessing such an object within a particular set of such objects in a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks~ Now I see. But is data set/data table is similar as hashtable as well?  When we add a column to a data table, they were actually create a hashkey for accessing the centain column? i.e myDataTable.Columns["MyColumn"]

Comment: Not all `O(1)` are created equal: [Big-Oh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) only talks about asymptotic behavior -- there may be a *really big* `C` in front: `C * O(...)`.

Comment: @King Chan: A hash table is pretty different from a data table. A data table is actually a two-dimensional structure. Accessing columns doesn't involve hash keys. A hash table isn't a table in the same sense, it's just a sort of sparse, randomized array.

Comment: @pst: That's true, but in this case the coefficients are similar enough.  For lists and arrays the coefficient is negligible and for hash tables it depends on the hash function.

Answer (score 2):

The amortized cost of finding an element by key with a Dictionary is O(1) or constant (also see ["Resizable hash tables and amortized analysis"](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs312/2005fa/lectures/amortized.html) for the CS fundamentals). The underlying data structure is not an array or list, but a hashtable - given an appropriate hashing function the speed of accessing a value cost does not grow significantly larger (hence is constant) with the number of elements, unless many or most of those elements have the same hash code.